# Struts if tag with iterator tag is not working

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jsp-tags, ognl

I am trying to use Struts `if` tag with iterator but it is not working.

Here is the code for this:

```jsp
<s:iterator status="i" value="pages" >
   <s:set var="kk" value="<s:property />" />     
                
   <s:if test="%{(#kk<5)}">
      Hello
   </s:if><s:else>
      Hi
   </s:else>                        
</s:iterator>
```

The `pages` list is a list of integers.

The above code should print `Hello` if `pages` value is less than 5 but print it for all values of `pages`.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "not working"

Comment: this code should print Hello if list value is less than 5 but it does not print it

Comment: Have you made any effort to debug this yourself, such as displaying the value of `kk` at that point?

Comment: yes I print the value of kk it is correct and I also try to test the condition for true using <s:property value="(#kk<5)" /> but it print true for all cases.

Comment: you cannot nest tags like that, it is invalid JSP, just like XML., the page would never have compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's so many options with OGNL, jstl and so on that it can become a nightmare to retrieve a value. Try with this one, I think in the following case the `%{}` is not mandatory

```
<s:iterator id="page" value="pages">
   <s:if test="#page < 5">Hello</s:if> <!-- or <s:if test="%{#page < 5}"> -->
   <s:else>Hi</s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: simply EL expressions not supported in the struts tags, many reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Should use

```
<s:set name="kk"  value="0" />
```

instead of

```
<s:set var="kk"  value="<s:property />" />
```

and you should not use `<s:` tag in the attribute of struts tags

```
<s:set name="kk" value="0"/>
<s:iterator status="i" value="bloglist" >
  <s:set name="kk"  value="%{#kk+1}" />
  <s:if test="%{(#kk<2)}">
    Hello<br>
  </s:if>
  <s:else>
  Hi<br>
</s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: name tag is deprecated by struts but I have already used it it does not work

Comment: different TLD taglibs this one is 2.2.3 but in another project I've used `var` atribute taglib version 2.2

Comment: But it doesn't matter what matters is you have undefined value for the `kk` variable.

Comment: As you code above where you are testing list value with kk you just increment it.

Comment: I'm not testing list value just testing `kk` variable value, and increment it on each cycle

Comment: your question about `if` statement that test `kk` variable

Comment: No I want to compare the kk value with the list value, where list is integer type in that case tell me what to do.

Comment: then you should write something `<s:if test="%{(#kk == id)}">`, where the `id` is a list value

Comment: you can also use reference `#i.count` to compare the list count

Comment: I saw you are using the list of integers referenced by `page`, that's rarely happens list may be the list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You do not even need to use `<s:set>`.

Just fully exploit the `Iterator` power:

```
 <s:iterator var="itr" status="ctr" value="pages" >    
    <s:if test="%{itr[#ctr] < 5}">
       Hello
    </s:if><s:else>
       Hi
    </s:else>    
 </s:iterator>
```